# svn: E155000 as maven tries to commit

Tags: maven, svn

As I run the maven goal release:prepare i get the svn error:

`svn: E155000 No write-lock in ...`

I tried different versions of SVN and maven. Tried to check out using tortoisesvn and command line. Asked out resident maven expert. 
Checked and re-checked settings.xml.

Anyone with a idea where to look?

ADD: It however seems like maven done the checkin. But the working copy still flagged as having local changes.

Complete message:

```
`[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3:prepare (default-cli) on project <project>: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] SVN commit failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] svn: E155000: Commit failed (details follow):
[ERROR] svn: E155000: No write-lock in 'C:\path...'
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException`
```

Comment: Please show the full output of the failure....

Comment: Do you have a commit hook on the SVN server? May it would be a good idea to update maven-release-plugin ? Which SVN Version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was at the end related to the settings.xml file. Rewrote it from scratch and got things to work. Probably something fishy with the setup of scm in the pom.

Thanks